# Input value shared between two browsers in angularjs application for the same url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, input

I am in a private network. I am using IE final version in windows 11v and latest Chrome. When I am typing in one form input textbox of url.biz/zzz/xxx.html in IE, it is showing up the same value in the form input textbox of the same url in Chrome as well. Its the first time I am seeing data shared between input boxes of two browsers in angularjs app. What is the exact issue, why would this happen, and how can I remove this update of input value data across browsers.

Comment: Is there any chance you're using Firebase or another websockets framework?

Comment: You haven't given much to go on here;  This isn't something that just happens magically in angular, we would have to see the code in question to know how or why, but debugging an entire app is a bit broad for this format.

Comment: No web sockets. No firebase. Even with backend xhr not happening the form values are the same across browsers and when I update it is updating the different browser form as well. Could be related to some settings in the os?

Comment: @claies - its a simple html code with binding to this syntax in the controller. Nothing more to it frankly. when same url is opened in chrome and ie then both the inout boxes of the same form is updated.

Comment: are you using browser sync or anything like that for development?

Comment: yeah I am using browser sync for development. these are my devDependencies - `"angular-mocks": "^1.5.0",  "browserify-replace": "^0.9.0",  "component-emitter": "^1.2.0",  "connect-livereload": "^0.5.2",     "serve-static": "^1.7.1"`

Comment: so then this is just `browser-sync` doing the job it was intended to do?

Comment: ok. it could browser-sync on a second thought. let me check.